# Oracle Query to get table list for which the current user has read access

Tags: oracle

How do I query an Oracle database to list the tables where the current user has read privilege?

Answer (score 11):

`user_tables` is users's tables. For all tables that user can read:

```
select * from all_tables;
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. This query list all tables including sys tables. I dont want sys tables. Can we filter here?

Comment: `select * from all_tables where owner in( 'SYS', 'SYSTEM' )` and exclude what you don't like. Or include only what you like. :)

Comment: `select * from all_tables WHERE TABLESPACE_NAME = 'USERS'` may help as well.

Comment: @Kyle Hi, that do not respond to the question. It just queries for tables where I have select grant and has the default tablespace = 'USERS'. A table may have any other default tablespace and I may see it or not.